# Firebase quickstart-js/messaging : Issue with Firefox push notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firefox, push-notification

I'm using the Firebase firebase-messaging-sw.js of quickstart-js/messaging as service-worker.

I'm correctly receiving web push notifications on Chrome and Opera, however I'm encountering some problems with Firefox.

This is the payload I'm sending via Firebase:

```
Header:
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
'Content-type' : 'application/json'

{
    "message": {
        "webpush": {
            "headers": {
                "TTL": "50"
            },
            "data": {               
                "message": "Custom body Message...",                
                "title": "Custom Title Optional"
            },
            "notification": {
                "icon": "https://...",
                "title": "Title...",
                "body": "body Message...",

            }
        },
        "token": "dSW3uSbvRZQ:APA91..."
    }
};
```

However, this is the payload that I receive on Firefox:

```
{
    from: "392777123950",
    priority: "normal"
}
```

The JSON post request is identical for the three browsers.
Moreover, I'm correctly receiving web push notifications on Firefox with this type of request:

```
{
     "message": {
       "token": "eym-3hyWckA:APA91bESbzQ2s3...",
       "notification": {         
         "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
         "body": "Great match!",
       }
     }
   }
```

I've read that Firefox uses Mozilla Auto-Push, could it be the reason of the different behaviour? Is there an issue with the HTTP v1 API?

Thanks.